# two-page layout with synced paragraph locations (xsl:fo / latex / docbook / ...)

Tags: latex, publishing, xsl-fo, docbook

I would like to have the following output in a pdf:

left side (odd page):

- paragraph A/1
- paragraph B/1
- paragraph C/1

right side (even page):

- paragraph A/2
- paragraph B/2
- paragraph C/2

I would like to position the paragraphs that B/1 begins *around* the same line as B/2, C/1 with C/2... Is there any method in xsl:of, latex, docbook stylesheet, any other publishing-related technology that supports this layout?

Comment: I've accepted the LaTeX-related answer because it definitely solves the problem. Please feel free to add other solutions with/without LaTeX, others might use xsl:fo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in LaTeX with the [parallel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parallel) package. It's most likely easy with [ConText](http://wiki.contextgarden.net).

Comment: "Provides a parallel environment which allows two potentially different texts to be typeset in two columns, while maintaining alignment. The two columns may be on the same page, or on facing pages." Excellent, thanks!